# Проблема с адаптацией сайта под смартфоны

Tags: html, css

Вообщем, решил адаптировать сайт под смартфоны, запустил сайт и получилось это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
@media screen and (max-device- 
width: 1048px){
```

Comment: А что не так?  Вроде симпатишно :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в head добавьте

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

И поменяйте:

```
@media screen and (max-device- 
width: 1048px){
```

на

```
@media(max-width: 1048px) {
```